# Apply tinymce 6.0 to a class of textareas

Tags: class, tinymce, selector

In tinymce 5.0, my init contained

```
mode : "specific_textareas",
editor_selector : "mceEditor",
```

in order to convert any textarea with the class "mceEditor" into a tinymce editor.  In 6.0, that doesn't seem to work.  It seems that "mode" is no longer used, and I found some docs on their site that said you can now select a single textarea using an ID by specifying:

```
selector : "textarea#elementid"
```

but I wasn't able to find any info on selecting textareas by class.  On a whim, I tried the following:

```
selector : "textarea.elementclass"
```

and it seemed to work.  But since I didn't see any docs referencing selection by class, I wanted to find out if this truly is the way to select multiple textareas based on their class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually [mentioned in the documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/basic-setup/#selector-configuration). The `selector` option utilizes the default CSS selector syntax:

> Selector configuration is required for TinyMCE integration. Selector
> configuration uses [CSS selector syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to determine which elements on
> the page are editable through TinyMCE.

Therefore, you were right when using

```
selector : "textarea.elementclass"
```